# ¿Como subir imagen desde un celular al servidor?

Tags: php, jquery, html5, phpmyadmin

tengo un problema para subir imágenes al servidor desde un dispositivo móvil (celular). Cuando ejecuto mi aplicación web desde el computador me funciona todo correctamente, las imágenes suben sin problemas. Pero cuando lo hago desde un celular no me cargan las o la imagen que se selecciona. les paso el código para que por favor me ayuden.

Este código no es directamente el que quiero solucionar, pero es prácticamente el mismo con menos validaciones pero igual tampoco sube la imagen cuando abro la página desde el celular (Con S.O Android).

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>formulario</title>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="crud.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form id="formulario" >
    <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen">
    <button type="submit" id="btnenviar">Enviar</button>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("body").on("click","#btnenviar", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formulario"));
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "servidor/upimage.php",
       data: formData,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       success: function (respuesta){
        alert(respuesta);

      }
     });

  });    
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 

    if ($_FILES["imagen"]['error']==0) {

        if ($_FILES["imagen"]['type']=="image/png" || $_FILES["imagen"]['type']=="image/jpg" || $_FILES["imagen"]['type']=="image/jpeg") {

            $target_path = "../";
            $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['imagen']['name']); 

            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
                { 
                    echo "El archivo ". basename( $_FILES['imagen']['name']). " ha sido subido";

                } else{
                    echo "Ha ocurrido un error con el archivo ". basename( $_FILES['imagen']['name']) ;
                }   
        }else{echo $_FILES["imagen"]['type']." Solo se pueden subir archivos tipo JPG, PNG Y JPEG.";}

        }else{

            echo "Por favor seleccione un archivo para subir";
        }
?>
```

Comment: Yo igual tengo el mismo problema algún me puede ayudar en este caso

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes saber si existe un error, para ello agrega una propiedad para cachear el error en tu petición ajax, algo así:

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "servidor/upimage.php",
       data: formData,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       success: function (respuesta){
        alert(respuesta);
      },
     fail: function(error){
        alert(error)
      }
 });
```

[Referencia](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Ya lo hice pero igual no sale ningún error, incluso el servidor  con las validaciones que tiene, dice que no se a seleccionado ningún archivo, como si uno no seleccionara ninguna imagen pero desde el celular en el PC me funciona perfecto.